# Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2 AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

getting this error when trying to Build my empty libgdx android studio project ..

Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.

Searched in the following locations:

```
file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/android-sdks/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/android-sdks/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/android-sdks/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/android-sdks/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

file:/C:/Users/Noor~.~/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712.pom

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha16-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha16-4748712-windows.jar
```

Required by:

```
project :android
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the repositories dependency on Google Maven. You need to edit your main `build.gradle` file to contain:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() //This!
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha16'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // And this!
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently changing the Gradle version fixed the problem for me. The Gradle version that is working is 3.1.3 but I'm not sure why that worked or if it will work for everyone.